# Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

```
Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

I installed webpack as a devDependency in my project and made a webpack.config.js in src folder

I tried the first answer according to this question but failed and do we need craco to solve this issue

[W](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)